# Cartesian product analogues for other Boolean operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Cartesian product of sets is build using conjunction.
$$F\times G=\{ (xy)| x \in F \land y \in G\}$$
Intuitive interpretation is: if you have set of figures and set of colors, direct product of those is set of all colored figures.
What are the names for Cartesian product analogues of other Boolean operations? What is their intuitive interpretation?
$$\{ (xy)| x \in F \lor y \in G\}$$
$$\{ (xy)| x \in F \implies y \in G\}$$
$$\{ (xy)| x \in F \iff y \in G\}$$
$$\{ (xy)| x \in F \triangle y \in G\}$$
**Update:**
Consider F is set of all numbers in interval [5,6] and G is set of all numbers in interval [2,4].[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these are actually sets (except if $F$ or $G$ are empty).

For example, assume $S:=\{(x,y)\mid x\in F\vee y\in G\}$ is a set, and fix any $g\in G$.
Then, for *all* $x$, the pair $(x,g)$ is in $S$.
Now let $X:=\{(x,g)\in S\mid x\notin x\}$. Obviously, we have either $X\in X$ or $X\notin X$. But $X\in X$ cannot hold, because this would imply $X\notin X$, a contradiction. So we know $X\notin X$. But since $(X,g)\in S$, this means $X\in X$, which is also a contradiction.

This is a version of Russell's Paradox, which you can check out on Wikipedia or on Numberphile's Youtube channel. What is boils down to is: Not everything that you can write down using set notation can actually work like a set.

Edit: Here's a nice video about Russell's paradox: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xauCQpnbNAM

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I was thinking about logic, I used set notation because of it popularity. I was thinking about abstraction $$(xy\[x \in F \lor y \in G])$$, I used Fitch book, he doesn' t use excluded middle as axiom in general. I am learning logic to understand set theory, because it is based on logic. I don't understand your proof could you advice small simple book with problems, such that after slowing them I would be able to understand your proof. IMHO Russel paradox shows that excluded middle is not universal principle.

Comment: Russell's paradox is a problem even without LEM. If you have a formula $\phi$ such that $\phi \to \lnot \phi$ holds you can deduce $\lnot \phi$; the Russell set $X$ satisfies $X \in X \leftrightarrow X \notin X$ so we may deduce both $X \notin X$ _and_ $\lnot (X \notin X)$, so we have a contradiction.